# correctly strip : char with Regex

Tags: python

I want to get words in a text string in python

```
s = "The saddest aspect of life right now is: science gathers knowledge faster than society gathers wisdom."

result = re.sub("\b[^\w\d_]+\b", " ",  s ).split()
print result
```

I am getting:

```
['The', 'saddest', 'aspect', 'of', 'life', 'right', 'now', 'is:', 'science', 'gathers', 'knowledge', 'faster', 'than', 'society', 'gathers', 'wisdom.']
```

How can I get "is" and not "is:" on strings that happen to contain `:` ?
I thought using `\b` would be enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you intended to pass a raw string to `re.sub` (notice the `r`).

```
result = re.sub(r"\b[^\w\d_]+\b", " ",  s ).split()
```

Returns:

```
['The', 'saddest', 'aspect', 'of', 'life', 'right', 'now', 'is', 'science', 'gathers', 'knowledge', 'faster', 'than', 'society', 'gathers', 'wisdom.']
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to make it a raw string literal (`r".."`)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "The saddest aspect of life right now is: science gathers knowledge faster than society gathers wisdom."
>>> re.sub("\b[^\w\d_]+\b", " ",  s ).split()
['The', 'saddest', 'aspect', 'of', 'life', 'right', 'now', 'is:', 'science', 'gathers', 'knowledge', 'faster', 'than', 'society', 'gathers', 'wisdom.']
>>> re.sub(r"\b[^\w\d_]+\b", " ",  s ).split()
['The', 'saddest', 'aspect', 'of', 'life', 'right', 'now', 'is', 'science', 'gathers', 'knowledge', 'faster', 'than', 'society', 'gathers', 'wisdom.']
```

Comment: One question and what about the period in `wisdom` ? how to get `wisdom` istead of `wisdom.`

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers pointed out you need to define a raw string literal using `r` like so: `(r"...")`

If you want to strip the periods, I believe you can simplify your regex to just:

`result = re.sub(r"[^\w' ]", " ",  s ).split()`

As you likely know the `\w` metacharacter strips the string of anything that is not a-z, A-Z, 0-9

So if you can anticipate that your sentences will not have numbers that should do the trick.